# Configure Visual Studio 2008 project with OpenCV 2.3

Tags: visual-studio-2008, opencv

I'm trying to setup visual studio 2008 with OpenCV 2.3.

I followed the instructions at: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide

When I reached step # 4 and chose Visual Studio which directs to the setup of OpenCV 2.1, I could not follow as I don't have lib and src folders in my extracted opencv folder.

Is there any other document that explains how to setup VS 2008 with this version of OpenCv? or is there any step that I might be missing to generate these folders?

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html#windows-installation) tutorial. It is a guide for VS2010, but it should give you a good idea of how to do it with VS2008.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can compile your librares or you can use the pre-compiled ones. The second is the easiest way, and I explain here how to do that, with instructions and a video (sorry, it's spanish but I think you will understand, it's just code):

http://devel-open.blogspot.com.ar/2012/12/opencv-visual-studio-2008.html